# How to add Firebase to a Java program (.java)

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I want to do is simple read a value (A Word/String) from a Google Realtime Database in a Java (.java) program in my computer, I've been looking for an answer but I only get information on how to do that with Android Java Apps (such as Android Studio Apps), but nothing like a library to do it in a Java program

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkt it out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?hl=en-us
If you are having trouble to find java code examples press ctrl + f and type java. If you're using maven just add.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
  <version>6.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new at programming in Java, where should I put the implementation if I have no gradle file? I am not using maven, I am just doing it in the Eclipse IDE

Comment: Hey bro =) it's fine everyone need's to start someday and you should not apologize for that. If you're not using anything to manage your dependencies you need to add the jar manually. Just click here http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-admin/6.11.0/firebase-admin-6.11.0.jar and add it to your project jars

Comment: I recommend you to watch some maven videos (just type it in youtube) because this tool really saves time. Let me know if the jar solution worked =)